# Why does the Navigation Bar stop working when used with a Tab Bar of style .page?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working with SwiftUI's Navigation Stack and Tab Bar/Tab Bar Style and before setting the tab bar style to page everything works as expected. Here is an example:

Code:

```swift
struct TabsView: View {
    enum Tab {
        case home
    }
    
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationStack {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Home Screen")
                        .navigationTitle("Home")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "square")
            }
            .tag(Tab.home)
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

But as soon as I add the `.tabViewStyle(.page)`, it breaks. It does not take up the full height as expected for the navigation bar. Also, the text is now hidden behind the navigation bar:

Code:

```swift
struct TabsView: View {
    enum Tab {
        case home
    }
    
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationStack {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Home Screen")
                        .navigationTitle("Home")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "square")
            }
            .tag(Tab.home)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That's because you have `NavigationStack` inside `TabView` as opposed to having `TabView` inside `NavigationStack`.

Comment: @ElTomato But each page (tab) should have its own navstack. You don't put a TabView in a navstack. Right?

Comment: @ElTomato, HangarRash is right with my approach. Each tab is supposed to have its own stack.

Comment: The one stack per tab rule only really applies to the default style not the page, their insides are different the page is not a "tab bar" in the UIKit sense. page is SwiftUI based (ZStacks) if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically speaking, if you don't have the Pages tab style (`.tabViewStyle(.page)`), you have both top and bottom safe areas covered as shown below.

[image]

So `Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()` is completely covered in the code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView1: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                NavigationStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text("Home Screen")
                            .navigationTitle("Home")
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                            .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                }
                .tag(Tab.home)
            }
            //.tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}
```

If you have the Pages tab style (`.tabViewStyle(.page)`), on the other hand, you lose both top and bottom safe areas as shown in the following pictures.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView2: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                NavigationStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text("Home Screen")
                            .navigationTitle("Home")
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                            .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                }
                .tag(Tab.home)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a similar layer whose color is close to that of the bottom safe area above `TabView` in the following.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView3: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.03).ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                NavigationStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        Text("Home Screen")
                            .navigationTitle("Home")
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                            .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                }
                .tag(Tab.home)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}
```

The following picture shows the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! That helps a lot. I understand why now.

Answer (score 2):

The `NavigationStack` for each `tabItem` rules applies to a "Tab Bar"

Per the "Human Interface Guidelines" a "Tab Bar" must be "[mutually exclusive](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-bars)".

In SwiftUI this is a `TabView` with a `DefaultTabViewStyle` because it uses a `UIKit` `UITabBarController`.

[image]

The `TabView` with `.tabViewStyle(.page)` is not a "Tab Bar" even though it is a `TabView`

[image]

```
NavigationStack { //Shared NavigationStack

    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            ScrollView {
                Button("switch \(isPage.description)") {
                    isPage.toggle()
                }
                Text("Home Screen")
                    .navigationTitle("Home")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "square")
        }
        .tag(Tab.home)
    }.tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! That helps a lot. I see how they are different and why I got them mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that the NavigationStack modifier is not compatible with the .tabViewStyle(.page) modifier. When you use .tabViewStyle(.page), SwiftUI creates a new navigation stack for each tab, which means that the NavigationStack modifier is not needed.

To fix this issue, you can remove the NavigationStack modifier and use the NavigationView modifier instead.

Like:

```
struct TabsView: View {
enum Tab {
    case home
}

@State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Text("Home Screen")
                    .navigationTitle("Home")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "square")
        }
        .tag(Tab.home)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLNHi.png)